# Domain containing polynomial ring over field, if finitely generated generated as module over it, is free as module over it

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomial-rings

This is the first part of exercise 4.2 from Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra" textbook. The problem is:

> Let $R$ be a domain containing a polynomial ring in one
> variable over a field, say $R \supseteq S = k[t]$. Show that if $R$ is a finitely generated
> $S$-module, then $R$ is free as an $S$-module.

The relevant chapter of the book, chapter 4, deals with integral extensions, the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, Nakayama's lemma, lying over and going up, Jacobson rings and the Nullstellensatz, so it's likely Eisenbud has a solution in mind involving at least one of these.

One thing I tried was viewing $R$ as a quotient $\frac{k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]}{J}$ for some $n$, so that $J$ is prime and contains a monic in $x_n$ (by Proposition 4.1 of the book), and seeking to show that $J$ is of the form $\langle p_2,\ldots,p_n\rangle$ with $p_i\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_i]$ monic. However this has proved difficult and now I'm not sure if it's even true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K=k(t)$, $W_1 = K \otimes_S R,M_1=R$. Then $W_1$ is a finite dimensional $K$-vector space and $M_1$ is a finitely generated sub-$S$-module of it, where $S=k[t]$ is a PID.

Take $m_1\ne 0\in M_1$, then $K m_1\cap M_1 = S b_1$ for some $b_1\in M_1$ (this is where we need that $S$ is a PID and that $M_1$ is finitely generated). Let $$M_2 = M_1/Sb_1, \qquad W_2 = W_1/Kb_1$$

And then repeat with $M_2,W_2$ which satisfy the same hypothesis, obtaining $b_2$ and then $M_3,W_3$, and so on.

$\dim_K(W_n)$ decreases at each step so the process terminates, and the obtained $b_1,\ldots,b_d$ are a free $S$-basis of $M_1=R$.

(take any representative in $M_1$ of $b_2$ which at first is in $M_1/Sb_1$)

Comment: Here it seems we're using the classification theorem for finitely generated modules over PIDs, so that they can be written as sums of cyclic modules, so that since $Km_1\cap M_1$ is a finitely generated $S$-module that injects into a cyclic $K$-module it can be seen that $Km_1\cap M_1$ has to be $S$-cyclic

Comment: Yes. $M_1$ is finitely generated so there is some $f\in S$ such that $f(Km_1\cap M_1)\subset Sm_1$. So $I = \{ g\in S, \frac{g}{f}m_1\in M_1\}$ is an ideal of $S$, ie. $I=(h)$ and $Km_1\cap M_1=Sb_1, b_1=\frac{gh}{f}  m_1$. @Blunka

Comment: Just realised if you use the classification theorem for fg modules over PIDs the exercise is pretty much immediate anyway